# Verifying Linearity and Shift Invariance Under Summation

Tags: linear-systems, homework, math

I am having some trouble working through verifying linearity and shift invariance when the transformation is under a summation.

The given transformation is as follows:
$$
y(m,n)=\sum_{i=-1}^{i=1}\sum_{j=-1}^{j=1}x(m+i,n+j)
$$

I understand the basics of verifying linearity ($T[a_1f_1(x,y)+a_2f_2(x,y)]=a_1T[f_1(x,y)]+a_2T[f_2(x,y)]$) and shift invariance ($g(x-h,y-k)=T[f(x-h,y-k)]$), but I am unsure how to apply them to the given transformation.  I could not find any other questions that covered this situation.  It has been a good while since I have had to do this math, so I am just getting back into the subject.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hint: let $x(m,n)$ be the $m$th row and $n$th column of an $M \times N$ image. Then, $y(m,n)$ is the 2D convolution of $x(m,n)$ with a 2D window of ones.

Comment: Funny, as this is related to image processing.  Could you explain a bit more about what you mean by the 2D window of ones?  Assuming it is discrete, then I could assume the summation is -1,0,1 for i and j?

Comment: See here: https://ai.stackexchange.com/a/20062/41856 and set $h[m,n] = 1$ for all $m,n$.